# PHP fwrite( ) Function with a stream file opened client socket stream

Tags: php, docker, sockets, tcpclient

I have a docker file that runs a geographical database server, and the container is up and running, in my backend, I am trying to make a TCP socket connection with that server
like below

```
class socketClient{

 private $_socket;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $server e.g. "localhost:6379"
     */
    public function __construct($address, $port)
    {
        $this->_socket = stream_socket_client($address.':'.$port);
    }

$cmd = "A native query that will be sent to my geographical server";

fwrite($this->_socket, $cmd); // writing my $cmd in the stream resource

$line = fgets($this->_socket); // getting the stream resource that I wrote in

 stream resource @52
     timed_out: false
     blocked: true
     eof: false
     stream_type: "tcp_socket/ssl"
     mode: "r+"
     unread_bytes: 0
     seekable: false
     options: []
   } // the $socket
}
```

the problem here is that I don't know where the **fwrite()** function writes my file does it create an actual file or does it write to the stream resource I don't know, when I try this on my local machine it works fine and the command sent to my database but after I moved to docker this line $line = fgets($this->_socket); returns a **false** which means there is no data has been written or some error happened, I am expecting the written command to the stream

Comment: You set `$socket =` but use `$this->socket`.

Comment: not really, it's for a demonstration purpose I will update my question